# can the loading iframe be transfered to popup if it takes too long to open?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, frameset

I have a web app that does a lot of background processing and I'm trying to see if there's a way to transfer iframe that is loading response to a popup, without reprocessing request, but continuing the initial request to iframe.

#### GOOD SCENARIO:

1. form is submitted, processing takes awhile to complete;
2. user was patient enough and stayed on the page long enough to get his response from the operation returned in the iframe
3. user will act according to the instructions in the iframe to complete request initiated in step #1

#### PROBLEMATIC SCENARIO:

1. form is submitted but processing takes too long to complete (3rd party might take up to 10 minutes to complete the request);
2. user doesn't want to stay on the same page and wait for the response to finish and clicks away to go to another page to continue his work in the application
3. response from iframe was never received from post in step #1 and processing results end up being unknown

#### EXPECTED SOLUTION:

What I'm trying to find out is whether there's a way for me to add an onunload event to the current page that would transfer iframe to a separate popup and that it would continue loading it and waiting for response, instead of initiating the new request? This way it would allow me to get users attention back to the popup once the processing is complete.

#### SIMPLE EXAMPLE FOR WHAT WOULD BE A GOOD WORKING SCENARIO:

1. Main app page has a form with a timer set to 60 seconds
2. -> user submits form (submit posts to iframe)
3. -> iframe starts countdown from 60 seconds
4. -> user navigates away from current page
5. -> popup gets opened up and it continues the countdown (instead of starting from scratch)

Comment: Most of the work involved in accomplishing this would have to be done server side. Are you looking for a client-side only solution?

Comment: AJAX and an implementation on both the client and the server would probably be the best solution.

Comment: I don't understand. What is this 60 second countdown? You know how long the processing is going to take? Are you not using AJAX to ask the server how far the process has come along?